# Geometric interpretation of the half-derivative?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, classical-mechanics, fractional-calculus, geometric-intuition

For $f(x)=x$, the half-derivative of $f$ is
$$\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}} x = 2 \sqrt{\frac{x}{\pi}} \;.$$
Is there some geometric interpretation of (**Q1**) this specific derivative, and, (**Q2**) of the half-derivative more generally? I have read that fractional derivatives are nonlocal,
but it seems strange to me that integral derivatives
can be described in terms of local
geometry only, while fractional derivatives cannot be so described.
This would suggest an odd discontinuity between, say, $d^{1}$ and $d^{1.01}$.
This seems especially at odds with [the many applications of fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Applications),
which (superficially) suggests continuity should reign.

I'd appreciate someone clearing up my elementary confusions—Thanks in advance!

**Addendum** (*5Jan14*).
@AlexR. found this geometric interpretation of
the fractional **integral** in Richard Herrmann's book,
*Fractional Calculus: An Introduction for Physicists*,World Scientific, 2011:

   [image: Fig5.1]

Comment: Well, my view of fractional derivatives is from it's kernel (by using Fourier transform), though this has nothing to do with  geometric interpretation. For integral derivatives,like $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}$, the Schwartz kernel is $\delta_0^{(k)}$, which measures only on a point, however, when considering the fractional derivative,like $\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, the respective kernel is $|x-y|^{-1-\frac{1}{2}}$, which is nonlocal anymore.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but it reminds me of [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108773/independence-of-leibniz-rule-and-locality-from-other-properties-of-the-derivativ), in whose answer locality of the derivative is obtained from the Leibniz rule.

Comment: I haven't found fractional powers of the first derivative $d/dx$, which is indefinite, to be of much use.  Fractional powers $\Delta^\alpha$ of the (analyst's) Laplacian $\Delta = -\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^2}$, on the other hand, are much more useful (note that the Laplacian is positive definite, in contrast to the first order operator.)  The square root of the Laplacian has a natural geometric interpretation as the Dirichlet-to-Neumann operator for the upper half-plane.

Comment: Also, fractional derivatives depend continuously on the exponent $\alpha$ (at least in the distributional topology), as can be seen on the Fourier side.  The non-locality disappears as $\alpha$ approaches a natural number due to denominators such as $\Gamma(-\alpha)$ that appear in the formulae for the kernel away from the origin (which is something like $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-\alpha)} |x-y|^{-1-\alpha}$ in one dimension).

Comment: Would it perhaps be appropriate to replace the deprecated tag 'geometry' with the tag 'geometric-intuition'? Also, would the top-level tag 'ca.analysis-and-odes' be adequate?

Comment: One obstruction to an obvious geometric interpretation is that the ordinary derivative can be regarded as generalizing to, for example, the exterior derivative, but I'm not aware of a generalization of the half-derivative this broad without extra structure (fractional powers of the Laplacian require a Riemannian metric, for example).

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Thanks; followed your tagging suggestions.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: the first order operator $d/dx$ is indefinite on the real line (the spectral variable $\xi$ can be either positive real or negative real), and so it is not natural to consider fractional powers of this operator (one has to arbitrarily choose a branch cut for $\xi^\alpha$).  But if one is working on the half-line instead, then the spectral variable $\xi$ now naturally lives on the upper half-plane (Fourier-Laplace transform) and one now has a canonical interpretation of $\xi^\alpha$.  So fractional powers of $d/dx$ are reasonable in half-line settings.

Comment: For what it's worth there is a nice geometric interpretation of a fractional *integral* in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=mPXzp1f7ycMC&lpg=PA26&ots=Bnx36egN51&dq=fractional%20derivative%20friction&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 52, figure 5.1.

Comment: The Fourier trf. really has very little to do with this operator, hand waving to the contrary. Similarly, $D^{-1}_{FT}g(x)=\int_{-\infty }^{x}g(u)du$, for Fourier integral ops from the Fourier convolution thm, convolving the Heaviside step fct $H(x)$ with $g(x)$, whereas $D^{-1}_{LPT}g(x)=H(x)\int_{0 }^{x}g(u)du$, for Laplace trf ops from the LPT conv. thm. Note that $FT(H(x))= 1/(i 2 \pi f) + \delta(f)/2$, whereas $LPT(H(x))= 1/p$

Comment: You can relate locality vs. non-locality to simple poles vs. branch cuts in the appropriate complex-contour/convolution integral reps for fractional differintegro ops of this type. The regular derivatives can also be evaluated with a nonlocal Cauchy contour integral, as well, with no singularity in the gamma fct.

Comment: See https://archive.org/stream/theoryoflinearop033341mbp#page/n39/mode/2up

Comment: In terms of Cauchy-like contour integrals, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125343/lie-group-heuristics-for-a-raising-operator-for-1n-fracdnd-betan-fra and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to/133194#133194

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A possible mechanical interpretation of the half-derivative can be given in terms of Abel's solution to a classical problem  from the calculus of variations ([the tautochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve)).

> Let there be a heavy particle which is constrained to slide without friction along
> the curve $y=y(t)$  in uniform gravity to its
> lowest point. Then, given a function $T(y)$ that specifies the total
> time of descent for a given starting height what is an equation of the
> curve that yields this result?

The principle of conservation of energy implies that the distance $S=S(t)$ travelled by the particle along the curve from the initial height $y_0$ satisfies the equation
$$\left(\frac{dS}{dt}\right)^2=2g(y_0-y).$$
This is equivalent to the integral equation
$$T(y_0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}\int_0^{y_0}\frac{1}{(y_0-y)^{1/2}}\frac{dS}{dy}dy.$$

The r.h.s. of the latter equation is nothing else but the [Riemann–Liouville fractional integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral) of $f=\pi^{1/2}(2g)^{-1/2}dS/dy$, i.e.
$$D^{-\alpha}f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^x (x-y)^{\alpha-1}f(y)dy$$
of the order $\alpha=1/2$.

The solution to Abel's integral equation $dS/dy$ can be now interpreted (up to a constant factor) as the half-derivative of $T=T(y_0)$.

[image]

Comment: And what is the heuristic interpretation of this... interpretation?

Comment: Beautiful!! Thanks for the lucid lesson!

Comment: How did you make that gif?

Answer (score 8):

A simple perspective for all fractional integro-derivative operators (FID) of this type is that they satisfy the group power sum property (law of exponents)

$$D_x^{\alpha}D_x^{\beta} = D_x^{\alpha+\beta}$$

and that their actions satisfy the dual translations

$$D_x^{\beta} \; H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} = H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha-\beta}}{(\alpha-\beta)!} = D_x^{-\alpha-1} \; H(x) \; \frac{x^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!} ,$$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. This is consistent with the rep of this action as the convolutional integral rep of the Euler beta function analytically continued via the Pochhammer contour or the methods of generalized functions/distributions. See below and my response to the MO-Q "[What's the matrix of logarithm of derivative operator (lnD)? What is the role of this operator in various math fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382735/whats-the-matrix-of-logarithm-of-derivative-operator-ln-d-what-is-the-rol/383563#383563)?" and the numerous links therein.

The Euler beta integral has a variety of physical, geometric, and probabilistic interpretations. See the MO-Q "[Connections to physics, geometry, geometric probability theory of Euler's beta integral (function)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218740/connections-to-physics-geometry-geometric-probability-theory-of-eulers-beta-i)".

---

Sinc function / cardinal series interpolation and a circular Fourier transform:

Let me summarize some old MO and MSE responses and blog notes for easy reference to relate the FIDs here to a Fourier transform on the circle and to hopefully clear up some confusion of this family of FIDs in fractional calculus with pseudo-diff ops/symbols related to Fourier transforms of continuous functions over the whole real line.

As mentioned above one (of several reps) for the action of the FIDs is the Euler beta integral rep

$$D_x^{\beta} \; H(x)\frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha!}=  H(x)\int_{0}^{x}\frac{z^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} \; \frac{(x-z)^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!}\; dz $$

$$= [ \; \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} \; \frac{(1-t)^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!} \; dt \;] \; H(x) \; x^{\alpha-\beta} .$$

Focusing on the Euler beta integral,

$$  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} \; \frac{(1-t)^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!} \; dt $$

$$= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} \; \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n!\;(-\beta-n-1)!} \; t^n \; dt$$

$$ =\frac{1}{a! (-\beta-1)!} \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n \binom{-\beta-1}{n} \; \frac{t^{n+\alpha+1}}{n+\alpha+1} \; |_{t=0}^1$$

$$ = \frac{(-\alpha-1)!}{(-\beta-1)!}\; \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-\beta-1}{n}\; \frac{\sin(\pi \; (n+\alpha+1))}{\pi(n+\alpha+1)}$$

$$ = \frac{(-\alpha-1)!}{(-\beta-1)!} \; \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-\beta-1}{n} \; \binom{0}{n+\alpha+1} = \frac{(-\alpha-1)!}{(-\beta-1)!} \; \binom{-\beta-1}{\alpha-\beta}   = \frac{1}{(\alpha-\beta)!}    $$

with the last two lines valid for all complex $\alpha$ and $Re(\beta) < 0$. A Hadamard finite part extension of the beta integral to all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be constructed as on p. 68 of Generalized Functions Vol. I by Gel'fand and Shilov.

A quick change of variables, reflecting the desirable property

$$D_x^{\beta} \; H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} = D_x^{-\alpha-1} \; H(x) \; \frac{x^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!} = H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha-\beta}}{(\alpha-\beta)!},$$

gives

$$  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{\alpha!}\;\frac{(1-t)^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!}\; dt =   \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t)^{\alpha}}{\alpha!}\;\frac{t^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!}\; dt ,$$

with the binomial expansion and subsequent sinc function interpolation for the RHS valid for

all complex $\beta$ and $Re(\alpha) > -1.$

Since the domains of validity of the two different avenues of expansion overlap to give the same result at their intersection, we have via analytic continuation an expression valid for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$, real or complex,

$$D_x^{\beta} \; H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} = D_x^{-\alpha-1} \; H(x) \; \frac{x^{-\beta-1}}{(-\beta-1)!} = H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha-\beta}}{(\alpha-\beta)!},$$

with the caveat (really an operator interpretation, see p. 57 of Generalized Functions Vol I (1964) by Gel'fand and Shilov)

$$H(x) \frac{x^{-n-1}}{(-n-1)!} = \delta^{(n)}(x) $$

with the standard Dirac delta interpretation

$$H(x) \int_0^x f(x-t) \; \delta(t) \; dt = H(x) \int_0^x f(t) \; \delta(x-t) \; dt = H(x) f(x).$$

A Cauchy integral rep gives the blow-up from the real line of the Euler beta integral to the complex plane, and, with a bit of regularization,

$$D_x^{\beta} \;H(x)\frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha!}= H(x)\frac{1}{2\pi i} \; \oint_{|z-x|=|x|}\frac{z^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} \; \frac{\beta!}{(z-x)^{\beta+1}} \;dz$$

$$ = [\; \frac{1}{2\pi i} \; \oint_{|z-1|=1}\frac{z^{\alpha}}{\alpha!} \; \frac{\beta!}{(z-1)^{\beta+1}} \;dz \;]  \; H(x) \; x^{\alpha-\beta}$$

$$ = [\;\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1+e^{i  \theta})^{\alpha} \; e^{-i \beta \theta} d\theta \; ] \; \frac{\beta!}{\alpha!} \; H(x) \; x^{\alpha-\beta}$$

$$ = [ \; \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{\alpha}{n} \; \frac{\sin(\pi \; (n-\beta))}{\pi(n-\beta)} \;] \; \frac{\beta!}{\alpha!} \; H(x) \; x^{\alpha-\beta} = H(x) \; \frac{x^{\alpha-\beta}}{(\alpha-\beta)!}.$$

Here, we have that the FID operation is equivalent to the Fourier transform over a circle (or an average of the Fourier transform of a periodic, in general piecewise continuous function over the real line)

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1+e^{i  \theta})^{\alpha} \; e^{-i \beta \theta} d\theta.$$

Added 2/3/21: As noted in other posts, this family of FIDs is also derived by Pincherle through an axiomatic approach, praised by Wiener, and presented in eqn. 4 of "The Role of Salvatore Pincherle in the Development of Fractional Calculus" by Mainardi and Pagnini. It is also consistent with Heaviside's operational calculus.

(I recall seeing eons ago that Ramanujan explored this last integral. Anyone have a ref?)

---

---

You would have to remain only in a very small circumscribed domain of mathematics not to have often encountered FIDs in one of their avatars.

In addition to the Euler beta function integral above, which played a role in the birth of string theory, they are encountered as [Kummer confluent hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) (KCHF, a.k.a. [generalized Laguerre functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191)), which lie at the heart of much of physics characterized by second order ODEs and vibrational analysis. The [Hermite polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40268/why-is-the-gaussian-so-pervasive-in-mathematics/383402#383402) are one especially prominent example, found in diverse fields from number theory, group theory, probability theory, to the theories of heat diffusion and Riemann surfaces.

The KCHF in integral form is

$$ \frac{M(a,b,z)}{(b-1)!} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{a-1}}{(a-1)!} \; \frac{(1-t)^{b-a-1}}{(b-a-1)!} e^{zt} \; dt$$

$$ = D_{t=1}^{-(b-a)}\frac{t^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}e^{zt} = e^{z}D_{t=1}^{-a}\frac{t^{b-a-1}}{(b-a-1)!}e^{-zt}.$$

Similarly the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function can be cast as

$$\frac{F(a,b;c;z)}{(c-1)!} = D_{t=1}^{-(c-b)}\frac{t^{b-1}}{(b-1)!}(1-zt)^{-a}.$$

Bessel functions can be related to FIDs as well.

Comment: This is a reasonable justification for the Hadamard finite part regularization/analytic continuation of throwing out the lower limit of integration, when $t =0$, when it gives infinity. // The analysis can be couched also as convolution theorems for the Laplace or the Mellin transform.

Comment: There is a universe of mathematics lying in between the complex differentiations and integrations. -- Heaviside

Comment: For two applications in physics of more general FIDs, see MathWorld on the Abel transform: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelTransform.html.

Comment: A brief, cogent discussion on Abel and the tautochrone problem starts on p. 19 of 'Construction and physical application of the fractional calculus" by Nicholas Wheeler https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Fractional%20Calculus/A.%20Fractional%20Calculus.pdf