# Why we use Caputo fractional derivative in application?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, differential-operators, semigroups-of-operators, fractional-calculus

I'm working on some papers which use Caputo fractional evolution equation ([see on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Caputo_fractional_derivative)) as application for thier main result:

For example:

> $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> ^CD^{\sigma}_tx(t)+Ax(t)=&f(t,x(t),\int_{0}^{t}k(t,s,x(s))ds)\:\:t\in J:=[0,b],
> \\ 
> x(0)=x_0&
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> where $^CD^{\sigma}_t$ denotes the Caputo fractional derivative of order $\sigma\in (0,1), $ $-A:D(A)\subset X\rightarrow X$ generates a positive $C_0$-semigroup, and $f$, $k$ are given functions.

**I'm wondering is this derivative important than the usual derivative, and why?**

**Can we provide a geometrical and physical interpretations for fractional derivatives like as integer order derivatives?**

PS: I need a good book or article about Caputo fractional derivative !

Answer (score 2):

Please see here a chapter from Diethelm, The Analysis of Fractional Differential Equations
An Application-Oriented Exposition Using Differential Operators of Caputo Type, Springer 2010: https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783642145735-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-993489-p174025563

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good place to start: [Properties and Applications of the Caputo Fractional Operator](http://homepages.vub.ac.be/~mishteva/papers/Ishteva_MScThesis.pdf).

For a geometrical/mechanical interpretation, you could look at this [MO question and answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/153542/11260).